# Acessar localhost Node JS pela rede

Tags: node.js

Criei um servidor com Node.js e preciso acessar por outra máquina na rede. Como poderia fazer isso?

Comment: Érico, realmente dependendo de como você constrói sua aplicação ele pode ter um comportamento diferente, vc pode atualizar a perguntar e adicionar parte do seu código que está criando o servidor?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Olá, tente acessar pelo ip da rede + porta.

por exemplo: 192.168.25.14:3000

Comment: eu estava tentando fazer isso, porem precisava do http:// antes do ip, obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Sério que era só isso?